# What's causing this NullPointer Exception?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm currently working on a project, that is runned on a GUI by using a JFrame.
I want to make as clear as possible what my problem is, i'm working in 3 packages (Entity, Control(Manager), Boundary(GUI)).
Boundary imports Control, Control imports Entity.

In the Entity package i got a shape class called "Block" that contains:

```
public class Block extends Shape 
//Shape is the parent of the class Block and a few other shapes
{
private int length, width, height;

public Block(int length, int width, int height){

    this.length= length;
    this.width= width;
    this.height= height; 
}
```

In the Control package i got a shape class called ShapeCollection
This stores the shape in an ArrayList

```
import Entity.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShapeCollection{

private ArrayList<Shape> shapecollection;


public ShapeCollection(){
    shapecollection= new ArrayList<Shape>();
}

public void addShape(Shape newShape){
    shapecollection.add(newShape);
}
}
```

In the control packages i got another class called ShapeController:

```
//This Controller is making the Shape 

import Entity.*;

public class ShapeController{
private ShapeCollection shapecollection;

public ShapeController(){
    ShapeCollection shapecollection= new ShapeCollection ();
}

public void makeBlock(double length, double width, double height)
{
    Shape shape = new Block( length,  width, height);
    shapecollection.addShape(shape);
}
```

In the Boundary(GUI) package i got a class called MasterFrame, this has to show a block created by a other frame called BlockFrame in a TextArea.

```
import Control.*;
public class MasterFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ShapeController shapecontroller;

public MasterFrame () {
    initComponents();
    vormComboBox.removeAllItems();
    vormComboBox.addItem("Select a shape");
    vormComboBox.addItem("Block");
     shapecontroller = new ShapeController ();
 // Here you get referred to a other GUI to make a shape in there, now i use BlockFrame
 // The code behind this works
}

 public static MasterFrame getInstance() {
    return MasterFrameHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private static class MasterFrameHolder{
    private static final MasterFrame INSTANCE = new MasterFrame();

} 

public void addTextBlock(double length, double width, double height) {

    vormcontrole.makeBlock(length, width, height);
    InfoShapeTextArea.setText("Block" + " "+ length + " " + width + "" + height);
}
```

Last class i use in boundary is BlockFrame:

```
import Boundary.ShapeController;

public class BlockFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   ShapeController shapecontroller;
   private double length;
   private double width;
   private double height;

public BlockFrame() {
    initComponents();

   shapecontroller= new ShapeController ();
}
```

When you press submit button it should make the Block and add it to the TextArea:

```
// The BlockFrame contains 3 textfields to store the doubles in and a submit button

private void BlokOkButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    MasterFrame h = MasterFrame.getInstance();


    length = Double.parseDouble(BlockLengthTextField.getText());
    width = Double.parseDouble(BlockWidthTextField.getText());
    height = Double.parseDouble(BlokHeightTextField.getText());


    shapecontroller.makeBlock(length, width, height);
    h.addTextBlock(length, width, height);
}
```

When i press the OK button to make a Block as shape i get this error:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"
at Control.ShapeController.makeBlock(VormControle.java:25)
at Boundary.BlockFrame.BlokOkButtonActionPerformed(BlockFrame.java:145)
```

What is causing this NullPointerException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these methods

```
private ShapeCollection shapecollection;

public ShapeController(){
    ShapeCollection shapecollection= new ShapeCollection ();
}

public void makeBlock(double length, double width, double height)
{
    Shape shape = new Block( length,  width, height);
    shapecollection.addShape(shape);
}
```

`shapecollection` is nowhere `initialized`.

in the constructor

```
public ShapeController(){
    ShapeCollection shapecollection= new ShapeCollection ();
}
```

You are not actually initializing the instance member. You are initializing a local variable.

Change it to

```
 public ShapeController(){
          shapecollection= new ShapeCollection ();
    }
```

Comment: it is initalized in ShapeController? I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Forza They're creating a method variable that shadows the `shapecollection` field of the object, not itilialising an object referenced by that field. This answer really could use some more words to explain what the issue is though.

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that the consructor initiates a local variable called shapecollection. The problem is, that the field shapecollection is not affected by this in any way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got this problem fixed now :)

Comment: It would probably be better form for initialize 'shapeCollection' at the same time you declare it (and make it final, unless you have a reason not to do so): 'private final ShapeCollection shapecollection = new ShapeCollection();'

Comment: Like-wise for length, width and height: you might be well served by making these final, unless you specifically want your Block class to be mutable.  Mutability has significant disadvantages above and beyond adding complexity (a single example: immutable objects can be safely shared between threads without synchronization).